# Code is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE9 array does not support indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792195/ie9-array-does-not-support-indexof)

My Code:

```
var arrFruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'dates'];
var position = arrFruits.indexOf( 'carrot' );
position > -1 && arrFruits.splice( position, 1 );
alert( arrFruits );
```

The above code is displaying the result as `apple, banana, dates` in `Chrome`. But it is not working in `IE9`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It triggers a syntax error? It alerts undefined? It makes the computer explode?

Comment: specify 'not working' do you get an error?

Comment: Works fine in  my IE9, but array indexOf probably does'nt work in IE8- [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnS8/)

Comment: is this the error that you're getting? "Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'"

Comment: I think this question is similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923434/ie-indexof-results-in-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method

Comment: No message is shown. `Alert` message is not popped up in `IE9` but popped up in `Chrome`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be issue of `.indexOf` not being supported. It basically is supported in IE9 unless some malicious doctype is triggering it to render page in IE7/8 mode. Than `Array.indexOf` method is not supported.

I suggest using HTML5 doctype for example (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) to make sure IE9 is rendering correctly.

Comment: I agree. Similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792195/ie9-array-does-not-support-indexof).

Answer (score 2):

till IE8 it doesn't have **.indexOf** method , [you can add it like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), if you are using IE9 [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825385/javascript-can-i-detect-ie9-if-its-in-ie7-or-ie8-compatibility-mode) for compatibility mode

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: IE9 does support array.indexOf ?

Comment: IE9 does support it. You just need to make sure the page is running in IE9 mode. Old doc types might cause it to run in IE7/8 mode. See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792195/ie9-array-does-not-support-indexof) for more info :

Answer (score 0):

What is  this line for

```
position > -1 && arrFruits.splice( position, 1 );
```

It evaluateto either `true` or `false` and then you don't do anything with it.that's probably causing a syntax error in IE, which the more forgiving Javascript engines on chrome and Firefox are ignoring.

Maybe you meant to make an `if` statement?

```
 if(position > -1) {
     arrFruits.splice( position, 1 ); 
}
```

Comment: Both solutions work fine on all modern browsers (though the second one is a lot clearer indeed).

Comment: I presume that means Ie9 treats && as a short-circuiting and? Is that part of the spec or just a convenient ms trick?